# GIT (TFS) error: Authentication failed on HTTPS pull

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our TFS build suddenly stopped working. As in: They worked before and I haven't consciously changed anything.

The culprit seems the TFS checkout. If fails now with the following error:

```
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9018180Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9191650Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9191750Z Task         : Get sources
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9191800Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9191850Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9191900Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9191950Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-02-17T15:05:01.9192010Z ==============================================================================
2020-02-17T15:05:02.3029550Z Syncing repository: repository (ExternalGit)
2020-02-17T15:05:02.3233340Z ##[command]git version
2020-02-17T15:05:02.3484980Z git version 2.21.1 (Apple Git-122.3)
2020-02-17T15:05:02.3701610Z ##[command]git config --get remote.origin.url
2020-02-17T15:05:02.3836900Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-02-17T15:05:02.3951910Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.http://tfs.***.org:8080/DefaultCollection/***/_git/***.***.extraheader
2020-02-17T15:05:02.4038750Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-02-17T15:05:02.4135610Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin http://***:***@tfs.***.org:8080/DefaultCollection/***/_git/***.***
2020-02-17T15:05:02.4241840Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin http://***:***@tfs.***.org:8080/DefaultCollection/***/_git/***.***
2020-02-17T15:05:02.4389440Z ##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-02-17T15:05:02.6933770Z fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://***:***@tfs.***.org:8080/DefaultCollection/***/_git/***.***/'
2020-02-17T15:05:02.6995380Z ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 2.49 seconds before retry.
2020-02-17T15:05:05.2443140Z ##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-02-17T15:05:05.4436380Z fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://***:***@tfs.***.org:8080/DefaultCollection/***/_git/***.***/'
2020-02-17T15:05:05.4445710Z ##[warning]Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 8.374 seconds before retry.
2020-02-17T15:05:13.8303720Z ##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-02-17T15:05:14.0495590Z fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://***:***@tfs.***.org:8080/DefaultCollection/***/_git/***.***/'
2020-02-17T15:05:14.0521190Z ##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
2020-02-17T15:05:14.0719800Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout
```

changing into the source directory and manually calling `git pull` works. So network, user id and password are ok.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How do you config your pipeline? If you create a new pipeline to get the same source, how's the result?

Comment: Did you recently change the password for you build agent? Did you try logged in as the build agent? It might have a cached password in the Windows Credential Manager with an old password and now failing to connect.  It does say authentication error in your log.